# JOINS vs. while statements

Tags: php, mysql, join, while-loop

In the company where I came to work, they run a PHP/MySQL relational database. I had always thought that if I needed to pull different info from different tables, that I could just do a simple join to pull in the data such as....

```
SELECT table_1.id, table_2.id FROM table_1 LEFT JOIN table_2 ON table_1.sub_id = table_2.id
```

When I got to where I currently work, this is what they do.

```
<?php $query = mysql_query("SELECT sub_id FROM table_1");
while($rs = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $query_2 = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table_2 WHERE id = '{$rs['sub_id']}'"));
    //blah blah blah more queries
?>
```

When I asked why the did it the second way, they said that it actually ran faster than a join. They manage a database that has millions of records on different tables and some of the tables are a little wide (row-wise). They said that they wanted to avoid joins in the case that a poorly executed query could lock up a table (or several of them). One other thing to keep in mind is that there is a massive report builder attached to this database that a client can use to build their own report and if they go crazy and build a big report, it could cause some havoc.

I was confused so I thought I'd throw this out there for the general programming public. This could be a matter of opinion, but is it really faster to do the while statement (one larger query to pull a lot of rows, followed by a lot of small tiny sub-queries if you will) or to do a join (pull a larger query one time to get all the data you need). As long as indexes are done properly, does it matter? One other thing to consider is that the current DB is in InnoDB format.

Thanks!

**Update 8/28/14**

So I thought I'd throw up an update to this one and what has worked more long term. After this discussion I decided to rebuild the report generator here at work. I don't have definitive result numbers, but I thought I'd share what the result was.

I think went a little overkill because I turned the entire report (it's pretty dynamic as far as the data that's returned) into a massive join fest. Most of the joins, if not all are joining a value to a primary key so they all run really really fast. If the report had lets say 30 columns of data to pull and it pulled 2000 records, every single field was running a query to fetch the data (because that piece of data could be on a different field). 30 x 2000 = 60000 and even under a sweet query time of 0.0003 seconds per query, that was still 18 seconds of just query time (which is pretty much what I remember it being). Now that I rebuilt the query as a massive join on a bunch of primary keys (where possible), that same report loaded in about 2-3 seconds, and most of that time was downloading the html. Each record that returns runs between 0-4 extra queries depending on the data that's needed (may not need any data if it can fetch it in the joins, which happens 75% of the time). So the same 2000 records would return an additional 0-8000 queries, (much better than 60000).

I would say that the while statement is useful in some cases, but as stated below in the comments, benchmarking is what it's all about. In my case, joins were the better option, but in other areas of my site, a while statement is more useful. In one instance I have a report where a client could request several categories to pull by and only return data for those categories. What happened was I had a `category_id IN(...,...,..,.., etc etc etc)` with 50-500 IDs and the index would choke and die in my arms as I was holding it in it's final moments. So what I did was spread out the ids in groups of 10 and ran the same query x / 10 times and my results were fetch *way* faster than before because the index likes dealing with 10 IDs, not 500, so I saw a great improvement on my queries then because of doing the while statement.

Comment: Benchmark it.  Your coworkers aren't going to change their minds because some guy on the internet says they're wrong.   Come up with a decent test case, and try it both ways.   But if you can show them hard numbers, how can they argue with that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the indexes are properly used, then it is almost always **more efficient** to use a JOIN. The emphasis is added because best efficiency does not always equal best performance.

There isn't really a one-size-fits all answer, though; you should analyze a query using `EXPLAIN` to ensure that the indexes are indeed being used, that there is no unnecessary temp table use, etc. *In some cases*, conditions conspire to create a query that just **can't** use indexes. In those cases, it *might* be faster to separate the queries into pieces in the fashion you've indicated.

If I encountered such code in an existing project, I would question it: check the query, think of different ways to perform the query, make sure that these things have been considered, build a scientific, fact-supported case for or against the practice. Make sure that the original developers did their due diligence, since not using a JOIN superficially points to poor database or query design. In the end, though, the results speak loudly and if all the optimizations and corrections still result in a slower join than using query fragments provides, then the faster solution prevails. Benchmark and act on the results of the benchmark; there is no case in software design that you should trade poor performance for adhesion to arbitrary rules about what you should or should not do. The best-performing method is the best method.

Answer (score 2):

It should be better to do the big query, if the indexes are well placed.

The logic behind it:

- 1 query = 1 call to the DB server, wich then processes the query (optimizer and all) and finally returns the result. N queries mean N calls to the database, including N calls to the optimizer and, in a bad case, I/O.
- MySQL has optimizations wich work on JOINs. Those optimizations can not work if you do a while.

As stated in previous answers, check with EXPLAIN if there is something wich isn't using an index in case you use the JOIN. Also, you should check the memory wich is given to the InnoDB cache, and the memory given to MySQL to parse a given query. Maybe it's because of those parameters that the database goes slower when doing the JOINs.

Answer (score 1):

I would say the answer is, it depends. Normally, I'd say joins are the answer, and doing multiple queries in a loop is bad practise, however, it depends entirely on what is being done.

Is it the case for you? Without detailed table structures and info on indexes as well as use of foreign keys etc, we can't say for sure. Best idea if you want to check, is try it and see. Get their queries, EXPLAIN them, write your own, and do an EXPLAIN on that, see which is more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about huge databases, but in my projects I always try to keep the queries to a minimum. Queries use harddrive access and (if not on same host) network access, which are slow. If there are many entries in that first query, you could be running thousands of queries per page which is going to be slow.

Answer (score 1):

Benchmark to find out the actual answer.

With the example you provided, it is highly unlikely that (with equivalent data) a join by the database will use more resources than setting up a new connection and perform the exact same operation (after all: you're still connecting the data in the same way as a join, even if it is externally done): if it was, the engine could simply be rewritten to use that external route to improve performance.

When joins use more resources (apart from indexing problems), it mostly comes from the downsides of retrieving the data per row, which means that information of the parent table will be duplicated in every row, even when this is redundant.

This may cause performance problems that can be helped by splitting queries if:

1. there are many children to one parent AND
2. you fetch lots of data from the parent (many columns or large fields)

In my experience, reducing the number of queries almost always benefits performance (I've optimized by combining queries far more than picking them apart).

The correct use of indices is good advice of course, but at first sight I don't think it will account for differences between those two scenarios, as the same indices (or lack of) would apply in both cases.